# How to cronly fill ajax form in django app?

Tags: django, cron

I have following problem:

I need my app to 
1. Go to https://airqualityegg.wickeddevice.com/download and fill out the form
(I found Django-cron package. Is it good idea to use it?)
2. Wait, while after js effects "Download file" button will appear
3. Download .zip file by clicking on that button
4. Extract from this .zip archive .csv file and work with it.
every 1 hour

What I gonna do?

Comment: You can use [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: Why are you using django for this? Makes more sense to write a standalone Python script (or whatever language works for you) and then configure it to run every 1 hour (with cron, systemd timer, etc). If the data is used in a django app and you want to save it in a model, then you can make a management command, but in the end the whole process you describe isn't really coupled to django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used selenium webdriver:

```
def get_zipfile_file_link(self):
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://airqualityegg.wickeddevice.com/download")
    driver.find_element_by_id("serial_numbers").send_keys(self.egg_id)
    driver.find_element_by_id("start_date").send_keys(timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=5))
    driver.find_element_by_id("zipfilename").send_keys("q")
    driver.find_element_by_id("download_submit").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 150).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a'))
    url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a').get_attribute('href')
    driver.close()
    display.stop()
    return url
```